# Core Data – When do I need to call save?

Tags: core-data, save

The scenario is this. I'm doing some some updates to an `NSManagedObject`. For instance setting the date `self.date = [NSDate now]`

Then I call a helper method in another class like this `[Utilities doFooWithObject:self];`

Do I need to call save between setting the date and calling the helper method? Will my helper method be able to access this recently set date without calling save between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with the object in the same managed object context, the new values will be available immediately.

In your case, you're just passing the object around directly, so it will be in the same managed object context. So you don't need to call `save:` at that point.